# Getting relative position of a MotionEvent inside a buttonView

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

```
private void buttonTouch(MotionEvent event, int num) {
    Log.v(TAG, num +" Button Click : X" + event.getX() + " Y:" +event.getY());
}
```

If the red square is a button view and the user clicks on it `event.getX()` seems to produce values on how the click is relative to the turquoise field or maybe even the whole screen. Is there an easy way how the click is located within the red square?

I see that there are function for getting the height and width of a button but I don't see a function that gives me one of the edges of the box or another way to know the exact location of the button so that I can use that to calculate where the click is relative in the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested this code and it gets the coordinates relative to the own view (a Button).

I've added a method to retrieve the width and height of the screen, just to get a global reference.

//Activity

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_activity);

        Button bt_test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_test_1);
        bt_test.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.v("TAG_TOUCH", " Button Click: X " + event.getX() + " Y: " + event.getY());
                Point point = getSizeScreen();
                Log.v("TAG_SIZE_SCREEN", " Width: " + point.x + " Height: " + point.y);
                return true;
            }
        });

        Button bt_test_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_test_2);
        bt_test_2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.v("TAG_TOUCH", " Button Click: X " + event.getX() + " Y: " + event.getY());
                Point point = getSizeScreen();
                Log.v("TAG_SIZE_SCREEN", " Width: " + point.x + " Height: " + point.y);
                return true;
            }
        });


    }

    private Point getSizeScreen() {
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        return size;
    }

}
```

//Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_test_1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt_test_2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The fact that it's works when there's a single button in the layout isn't very useful.

Comment: I've edited my answer with two buttons. And still works (not surprising). Maybe I don't understand what are you trying to achieve, anyway.

Comment: Given your code if I click in the middle of the right button I get a different value than when I click in the middle of the left button. I want the same value.

Comment: Well, It doesn't happen to me xD They return the same value. Have you tried it just like I posted? -without any modifications. Really, I don't know how it is even possible.